# Can I wait for a js process within PHP before continuing?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a PHP script I use to register users but during that process I'm trying to call a Google GEOCoding javascript method to return the client lat/lng and record it to a DB before continuing with my PHP registration process.

Can this be done or is there a better way?

My current code looks something like this:

```
private function process() {

    $this->validate();
    $this->register();

    // execute javascript here to record lat/lng coordinates to the DB. 

    $this->goHome();
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no. Can't you do the geocoding stuff directly from PHP?

Comment: Since php runs on the server and javascript runs on the client, this simply isn't possible the way you ask.  What you could do is pass the info via javascript & ajax when the page has loaded, and have a separate php function to save that.

Comment: As long as you are not refering to server side javascript, you have not understand the basics of a web application.

Comment: You could embed JavaScript in the page you send out that could send the location back to you with an Ajax call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need javascript. The Google Geocoding API is a web service. In PHP, just do a [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and issue the request using the proper url format as [described here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests). You'll then need to run the result through PHP's [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can't just run JavaScript in a PHP script. PHP is executed on the server, and JavaScript is executed in the client's browser. You should modify your registration form so that the JavaScript is called before the form is submitted, and you should pass the user's lat/lon as extra data for registration. Then, when your PHP registration runs, you'll have access to this data.

<s>A better idea would be to find a PHP library to do geocoding.</s>
See Johnathan M's answer.

Comment: But then the user can modify the data before it is sent.
Better do this with PHP on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a clientsided script language
Php is serversided

This makes it impossible the way you imagion to do it.

Take a look into GeoIP
http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Answer (score 0):

You generally handle only one request in script and what you asking about would require at least two: in first user would ask for some response from your server and you'll be able to send your JS to him and in second request he'd submit results of running that JS.

You can save "state of waiting for response" in some way and process geo response when it comes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve your issue would be to use 2 AJAX calls and a function: 
- the first calls a PHP script to do your validation/ registration 
- when this completes run a clientside JS script to do the geocoding
- have another AJAX call to update the DB with the result of geocoding

You should be able to solve your problem this way. If you use a library like jQuery its easy to do the AJAX calls and you can even make use of deferred objects, which I think could help you chain your calls http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 0):

Do the GeoIP lookup in PHP using a web API instead on the server side.

For example:
http://www.maxmind.com/en/web_services

They have a PHP example here (I wouldn't call the webservice that way, but it works):
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/web-services#PHP-11

```
private function process() {

    $this->validate();
    // Do a call to the webservice here with PHP, update user data with the response.
    $this->register();

    $this->goHome();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to go about it.

The best appoach would be to make the geocaching call within your PHP, not using javascript all. PHP has several ways of making HTTP requests from code, that will return results you can use in your script. I personally favor cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. See also Jonathan M's earlier reply, same idea but using file_get_contents().

Another (far hackier) approach would be to make the javascript call to the Google Geocoding API synchronous (async=false in jquery.ajax()), and have it execute your request to your registration php page through a callback on the ajax call. (The "success" property on the ajax.) This means that your registration page will not be called until the geocoding lookup is completed. It's a valid question whether you want to make success/failure of your registration dependent upon completion of the ajax request, but if you do, this would work. Check here for info on synchronous ajax requests in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. This really isn't the best way to go about it though. The geocoding lookup really is part of the registration, and the last thing you want to do is make your php registration dependent on unreliable frontend behaviors.

Comment: It's a really, really, *really* bad idea to use `async=false`. There's always a better way to do it than to do that. Take that as coming from someone who bears the scars of having made that mistake. :)

Comment: Thinking about it objectively as I can, you're probably right. The latter approach I suggested (basically the same as yours) is far better. Worth an edit of my post.